# ROC Curve using a Perl Module?

Tags: perl, roc

Is there a Perl Module which is capable of plotting ROC curves please? I know one exists for [the R programming language](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/), but I can't find one for Perl. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Statistics::ROC`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aROC) computes the curves.  You'd have to plot them with any number of graphics tools.

Comment: What graphics tools do you recommend please?

Comment: There are several plotting modules for PDL. Try [PDL::Graphics::Prima::Simple](http://p3rl.org/PDL::Graphics::Prima::Simple) or [PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot](http://p3rl.org/PDL::Graphics::Gnuplot) among others.